# Generics Type casting?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-factory

In a abstract factory pattern i am using generics.
I have BaseEntity interface which extends Serializable, the Employee class implements the BaseEntity. 
In the abstract class i have this getJavaObj method

`getJavaObj()` is a method which takes a `Long empId` and returns a `Map<String, ? extends BaseEntity>`

```
public abstract Map<String, ? extends BaseEntity> getJavaObj(Long id);
```

Using generics i am trying to do this in the main class it gives;

```
Map<String, Employee> emp = getJavaObj(empId);
```

It gives this error Type safety: **Unchecked cast from `Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends BaseEntity>` to Map**

When i do the type casting like this

```
Map<String, Employee> emp = (Map<String, Employee>)getJavaObj(empId);
```

It gives this warning

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from `Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends Serializable>` to 
>                Map
>   Type safety: Unchecked cast from `Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends BaseEntity>` to 
>                Map

**Is there a way to avoid type-casting or resolve the warnings even after typecasting?** Since the object i am returning does extend to the Serializable via BaseEntity interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine your factory method:

```
public abstract <T extends BaseEntity> Map<String, T> getJavaObj(Long id);
```

Then you can get the correct type back without a cast:

```
Map<String, Employee> emp = getJavaObj(empId);
```

Comment: Couldn't they simply add a generic type arg to the method instead of a class parameter? As in `public abstract <T> Map<String, T extends BaseEntity> getJavaObj(Long id)`? Or am I forgetting something important about generic method args?

Comment: @TomG - That would work just as well. I assumed that T was already a class parameter. Post that as an answer and it will probably get a green check mark. :)

Comment: @TedHopp in the abstract class, it does'nt allow as you suggested. It gives error and suggests: Multiple markers at this line
 - The type parameter String is hiding the type 
  String
 - This method requires a body instead of a 
  semicolon
 - Return type for the method is missing
 - Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Comment: @silver_mist - Yeah, I had the syntax a bit screwed up. I've edited the suggested code. This at least compiles for me.

Comment: @TedHopp with this while implementing the method when i try to create employee object in the getJavaObj(), gives compilation error "cannot instantiate the type Employee". Why is it so?

Comment: @silver_mist - I don't know. I'd have to see the code. Is `Employee` an abstract class? Also, why do you need to create an instance of `Employee`; is it to populate the map at the same time you are creating it? Perhaps you should post this as a separate question, along with the relevant code.

Comment: @TedHopp Employee is a class, in a abstract class `public abstract <T extends BaseEntity> Map<String, T> getJavaObj(Long id);` is there. In a service class i am seeting the fields of the employee in the getJavaObj() which returns a map of type Map<String, Employee>

Comment: @silver_mist - Please post your code and the problem in a new question. It's impossible to understand what your code structure is from the brief excerpt in your comment.